# How to build a versioned (or checksummed) file using shake-build?

Tags: shake-build-system

My Elm build commands produce a versioned/checksummed JS file, which looks like `main.[checksum].js`. How do I handle this with `shake` (specifically, I can't figure out how to write the `want`declaration for this, as the filename would change every time).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little fiddly to model, but an intermediate file works well. When generating `main.[checksum].js` you also generate `main.txt` which contains the checksum within it. Depending looks like:

```
wantElm x = do
    src <- readFile' (x </> "main.txt)
    want [src]
```

And generating looks like:

```
generateElm = do
    "**/main.txt" %> \out -> do
        Stdout hash <- cmd "elm build" out
        writeFile' out hash
```

That assumes Elm tells you the hash on stdout, but easily adapts to however you do find the hash.

Comment: I'm still stuck wit this one (and the scope of the original question has expanded). Here's what I'm trying to do: If my `elm-src//*` folder has changed, it should trigger N elm builds to produce N checksummed JS files. However, these N builds **must be run serially** (irrespective of `shakeThreads`) due to a subtle bug in the Elm compiler.

Comment: I've gotten the following to work - https://gist.github.com/saurabhnanda/835b359f7996a9459ac9101c1d087f4f - but it's very brittle. It does not re-run if the checksummed file is deleted from the `dist` folder, because shake doesn't know about its existence.

Comment: To avoid running serially, use Resources in Shake. I'd still go for a pattern where each rule is a separate rule, more like the answer above than like the gist you linked to.